# How to calculate weighted average balance in sql between two months

Tags: sql-server

How can I calculate WtdAvgBal in SQL for two months that are not quarter end months (March,June,September,December) and append values in the dataset.

Dataset:

| Date | ID | AvgBal | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/31/2020 | 1 | 50 | M |
| 7/31/2020 | 2 | 75 | M |
| 7/31/2020 | 3 | 50 | M |
| 7/31/2020 | 4 | 50 | M |
| 7/31/2020 | 5 | 50 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 1 | 55 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 2 | 99 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 3 | 80 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 4 | 70 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 5 | 90 | M |

Total days in the two periods: 62 days (31 in July, 31 in August)

WtdAvgBal calculation steps that is done in excel.

1. create a new column to get Bal * day value for each row.

| Date | ID | Bal | Period | Bal x Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/31/2020 | 1 | 50 | M | 1550 |

2. Add total days in the two months observed.  (eg. 62 day in July and August)

   Total Days: 62
3. Calculate WtdAvg using excel's sumif formula in the AvgBal column and apply it to the most recent month in the dataset.

   =sumifs(@Bal x Day, @ID, ID) / 62

Avg bal output Output:

| Date | ID | AvgBal | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/31/2020 | 1 | 52.5 | X |
| 8/31/2020 | 2 | 87 | X |
| 8/31/2020 | 3 | 65 | X |
| 8/31/2020 | 4 | 60 | X |
| 8/31/2020 | 5 | 70 | X |

Append the new period X into the dataset

Final Output:

| Date | ID | AvgBal | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/31/2020 | 1 | 50 | M |
| 7/31/2020 | 2 | 75 | M |
| 7/31/2020 | 3 | 50 | M |
| 7/31/2020 | 4 | 50 | M |
| 7/31/2020 | 5 | 50 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 1 | 55 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 2 | 99 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 3 | 80 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 4 | 70 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 5 | 90 | M |
| 8/31/2020 | 1 | 52.5 | X |
| 8/31/2020 | 2 | 87 | X |
| 8/31/2020 | 3 | 65 | X |
| 8/31/2020 | 4 | 60 | X |
| 8/31/2020 | 5 | 70 | X |

Comment: It would be the best if you can tell us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Following GROUP BY query will gives you the required value for 'X'

```
select Date   = max(Date), 
       ID, 
       AvgBal = sum(AvgBal * datepart(day, Date) * 1.0) / sum(datepart(day, Date)),
       Period = 'X'
from   Dataset
group by ID
```